# Finding whether there is any overlap between two date periods in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following `pd.DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'admission_timestamp': ['2021-01-17 17:45:00', '2020-03-31 23:32:00', '2020-03-27 18:20:00', '2020-04-17 18:12:00', '2020-03-19 19:12:00'], 'end_period': ['2021-01-18 17:45:00', '2020-04-01 23:32:00', '2020-03-28 18:20:00', '2020-04-18 18:12:00', '2020-03-20 19:12:00'], 'start_med': ['NaT', '2020-04-01 00:00:00', '2020-03-27 19:00:00', '2020-04-17 18:39:24', 'NaT'], 'end_med': ['NaT', '2020-04-14 21:00:00', '2020-04-05 00:00:00', '2020-05-06 22:07:29', 'NaT']})
```

that looks like:

```
   admission_timestamp  end_period           start_med            end_med 
1  2021-01-17 17:45:00  2021-01-18 17:45:00  NaT                  NaT   
2  2020-03-31 23:32:00  2020-04-01 23:32:00  2020-04-01 00:00:00  2020-04-14 21:00:00
3  2020-03-27 18:20:00  2020-03-28 18:20:00  2020-03-27 19:00:00  2020-04-05 00:00:00
4  2020-04-17 18:12:00  2020-04-18 18:12:00  2020-04-17 18:39:24  2020-05-06 22:07:29   
5  2020-03-19 19:12:00  2020-03-20 19:12:00  NaT                  NaT
```

I want to create a new column `received_medidation` that states whether or not (boolean) the patient received medication between `admission_timestamp` and `end_period` (even if it was for only one second). So, the boolean should state if there is any time between `admission_timestamp` and `end_period` that overlaps with the time between `start_med` and `end_med`. The dtypes are all *datetime64[ns]*.

I know that we can create boolean masks such as

```
condition = (df['date'] > start_date) & (df['date'] <= end_date)
```

... however I fail to understand how this could possibily solve the task above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to do the comparison row by row?

Comment: @Corralien I want to create a new column that states whether or not the medication was received during that period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `start_med` is guaranteed to be later than `admission_timestamp`, then it suffices that `start_med` date is between `admission_timestamp` and `end_period`

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

df['received_medidation'] = (df['admission_timestamp'] < df['start_med']) & (df['start_med'] < df['end_period'])
```

If however, `start_med` can be before `admission_timestamp`, then that means `'start_med' < 'admission_timestamp' < 'end_med'` also creates an intersection of dates. Then we include this case with the previous case using OR operator:

```
df['received_medidation'] = (df['start_med'].between(df['admission_timestamp'], df['end_period']) |
                             df['admission_timestamp'].between(df['start_med'], df['end_med']))
```

**Note**: The overall assumption here is that it's always true that `admission_timestamp < end_period` and `start_med < end_med` , in which case the above logical expression catches all intersecting dates.

Output:

```
  admission_timestamp          end_period           start_med  \
0 2021-01-17 17:45:00 2021-01-18 17:45:00                 NaT   
1 2020-03-31 23:32:00 2020-04-01 23:32:00 2020-04-01 00:00:00   
2 2020-03-27 18:20:00 2020-03-28 18:20:00 2020-03-27 19:00:00   
3 2020-04-17 18:12:00 2020-04-18 18:12:00 2020-04-17 18:39:24   
4 2020-03-19 19:12:00 2020-03-20 19:12:00                 NaT   

              end_med  received_medidation  
0                 NaT                False  
1 2020-04-14 21:00:00                 True  
2 2020-04-05 00:00:00                 True  
3 2020-05-06 22:07:29                 True  
4                 NaT                False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `between`

```
df['overlaps'] = df['start_med'].between(df['admission_timestamp'], df['end_period']) \
                 | df['end_med'].between(df['admission_timestamp'], df['end_period'])
print(df)

# Output
  admission_timestamp          end_period           start_med             end_med  overlaps
1 2021-01-17 17:45:00 2021-01-18 17:45:00                 NaT                 NaT     False
2 2020-03-31 23:32:00 2020-04-01 23:32:00 2020-04-01 00:00:00 2020-04-14 21:00:00      True
3 2020-03-27 18:20:00 2020-03-28 18:20:00 2020-03-27 19:00:00 2020-04-05 00:00:00      True
4 2020-04-17 18:12:00 2020-04-18 18:12:00 2020-04-17 18:39:24 2020-05-06 22:07:29      True
5 2020-03-19 19:12:00 2020-03-20 19:12:00                 NaT                 NaT     False
```

Comment: I just realized that the `start_med` can occur before `admission_timestamp`. In that case, `start_med` is < `admission_timestamp` and `end_med` could be > `end_period`. Then we cannot use `between`, do you have a solution for that?